# How can I fuse two meshes together and remove the inside faces?

Tags: modeling

I have these two meshes (helmet body and the lower pipe).
I want to fuse them together so that the outer edges all connect but the inside faces are deleted. Is there a way to do that?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can enable the "Bool Tool" addon and press "Union" button to merge the meshes selected.

[image: Bool tool union]

Here is the [documentation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/object/bool_tools.html) of "Bool Tool" Addon.